# Javascript: What are the best tools for manipulating a javascript based website?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm not going to try to dilly dally around: I'm a student on a college campus and I'd like to be able to invite all my friends on facebook to events I create without having to click all of their names manually.

I'm fairly familiar with Javascript; my only issue is that the scripts appear to be fairly obfuscated (probably on purpose) and I'm wondering what the best technique would be to tackle this task.  I've tried the chrome developer toolbar, but I don't think it's quite what I'm looking for (although I could just be using it wrong).

Comment: Not sure what the actual question is... specifically.

Comment: @Kon - I mean, I just want to know what tools would be best to handle the task.  Or techniques.  Or advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [GreaseMonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) script which would programmatically click on all the names for you.

Comment: Ah, completely forgot about GreaseMonkey.  Thanks, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug for Firefox is a good tool for breaking down the JavaScript objects on a page. It's one of the leading debuggers for JavaScript. You can't go wrong with it as a tool for seeing how their code finally runs once the browser is done loading it.